# scala convert string into a list of longs

Tags: scala

I have a question. I work on legacy code and I found this in scala. I'm supposed to do some code refactoring.

```
val elements: List[Map[String, String]] = calculateElements(south, west, north, east)

elements.foreach { e =>
  if (e("type") == "way") {
    var way_nodes = e("nodes").asInstanceOf[List[Long]]
    ...
  }
}
```

This code works fine, but when I try to move this method to another project so I can test it, It fails.

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List
```

Is it possible to convert a String into a List of Long?

Old code runs in Scala 2.8.1 and new test project runs in Scala 2.11.2.

Comment: Well... If by convert you mean type-casting by using `asInstanceOf` then `NO` you can not type-cast `String` to whatever your `Long` is, unless `Long` is a `subclass` of `String` ( which is not true as we all know that `Long` is not a subclass of `String` ). And if you talk about `List[ Long ]` then answer is a definite `NO`.

Comment: And some how... I find it really really hard to believe that this code works with any version of Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `e("nodes")`, assume a comma separated string of integral values,

```
val nodes = "123,  -2, 0, 67"
```

To convert such string onto a collection of `Long`, consider for instance

```
nodes.split(",").map(_.trim.toLong)
Array[Long] = Array(123, -2, 0, 67)
```

Note also a `String` in Scala is equipped with methods from ordered collections so that `String` may be treated as a sequence of `Char`. Thus, assuming now that the original string is of this form,

```
val nodes = "43217"
```

and wish to convert it into a collection of `Long`, then

```
nodes.map(_.asDigit.toLong)
Vector(4, 3, 2, 1, 7)
```

Yet, the following converts each char in a string onto its associated ASCII numerical value,

```
nodes.map(_.toLong)
Vector(52, 51, 50, 49, 55)
```

Answer (score 1):

if it is input from the source that is not totally controlled by you, then you should add more checks to take care of the following scenarios.

```
scala> " ".split(",").map(_.trim).filter(_.length > 
0).map(_.toLong).toList
res3: List[Long] = List()

scala> "12, 34".split(",").map(_.trim).filter(_.length > 
0).map(_.toLong).toList
res4: List[Long] = List(12, 34)

scala> "12,34".split(",").map(_.trim).filter(_.length > 
0).map(_.toLong).toList
res5: List[Long] = List(12, 34)
```

So, the simplest (without hiding the potential java.lang.NumberFormatException, if you are expecting input to be at most only contains digits and comma), then the following should be sufficient

```
 <your variable>.split(",").map(_.trim).filter(_.length > 
0).map(_.toLong).toList
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be relevant to the question (whatever the question is...).